# Repeat ACF field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to create my own MP3 playlist with HTML5/JS player and ACF Pro. Every thing is ok but I just have 1 Track in my playlist and it seems my JS code need to be repeat at the audio part.

So this is my php/js code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('playlist_single_track') ): ?>                                              
<?php while( have_rows('playlist_single_track') ): the_row();                           
$pltrackname = get_sub_field('playlist_track_name');
$pldownloadtrack = get_sub_field('playlist_track_download');
$plplaytrack = get_sub_field('playlist_trak_online_player');
?>  

<script>
const ap = new APlayer({
    container: document.getElementById('playlist'),
    listFolded: false,
    listMaxHeight: 90,
    preload: 'none',
    audio: [
        {
        name: '<?php echo $pltrackname; ?>',
        artist: 'null',
        url: '<?php echo $plplaytrack; ?>',
        cover: 'images/cover.jpg'
        },
    ]
});

</script>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know much about javascript so can you help me to repeat JS code in this part:

```
    {
    name: '<?php echo $pltrackname; ?>',
    artist: 'null',
    url: '<?php echo $plplaytrack; ?>',
    cover: 'images/cover.jpg'
    },
```

It will help me to add more song tracks in my playlist.

I need to do something like this:

```
<script>
const ap = new APlayer({
    container: document.getElementById('playlist'),
    listFolded: false,
    listMaxHeight: 90,
    preload: 'none',
    audio: [
        {
        name: 'track1',
        artist: 'artistname',
        url: 'URL1',
        cover: 'images/cover.jpg'
        },
        {
        name: 'track2',
        artist: 'artistname',
        url: 'URL2',
        cover: 'images/cover.jpg'
        },
        {
        name: 'track3',
        artist: 'artistname',
        url: 'URL3',
        cover: 'images/cover.jpg'
        },
    ]
});

</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
<?php if( have_rows('playlist_single_track') ): ?>
<script>
const ap = new APlayer({
    container: document.getElementById('playlist'),
    listFolded: false,
    listMaxHeight: 90,
    preload: 'none',
    audio: [                                              
<?php while( have_rows('playlist_single_track') ): the_row();                           
$pltrackname = get_sub_field('playlist_track_name');
$pldownloadtrack = get_sub_field('playlist_track_download');
$plplaytrack = get_sub_field('playlist_trak_online_player');
?>  


        {
        name: '<?php echo $pltrackname; ?>',
        artist: 'null',
        url: '<?php echo $plplaytrack; ?>',
        cover: 'images/cover.jpg'
        },

<?php endwhile; ?>
    ]
});

</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```